# Запятая и тире.

Tags: пунктуация

Насколько я знаю, в школьной программе этот материал опускается,но все же хочется узнать.
Как, например, объяснить постановку знаков в предложении:
**"Последний взгляд в зеркало убедил ее, что она внушительно красива, - красива добротной и прочной красотой смолистой сосны. (Максим Горький)"**?

Answer (score 2):

Я не вижу (и не чувствую) здесь однородных придаточных. Скорее, здесь пояснительная конструкция: чем именно красива? А так как никакие пояснительные слова не использованы, и стоит тире.

Answer (score 1):

Это сложноподчинённое предложение с двумя однородными придаточными. Второе придаточное - неполное предложение. 
Я думаю, что тире объясняется пропущенными членами предложения (точнее подлежащим) во втором придаточном предложении, ср.: ***" Последний взгляд в зеркало убедил ее,что она внушительно красива,*** что она ***красива добротной и прочной красотой смолистой сосны.***" Тире позволяет избежать повтора. А запятая перед тире отделяет первое придаточное предложение от второго.

Answer (score 0):

Тире знак во многом факультативный, тут можно разные толкования искать, мне ближе сформулированное [[@Ларf](/users/498/%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80f)](/users/498/%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80f). Хотя и соображения о графическом исключении повтора не лишено смысла. 
Но следует ещё иметь в виду особенности авторской пунктуации. Горький, все-таки. Для него интонационные тире вообще характерны.

Comment: Нашел кое-что по этой теме:" Запятая и тире выступают как единый знак препинания перед словом, которое повторяется  для того, чтобы связать с ним новое предложение (чаще придаточное) или дальнейшую часть того же предложения".
Например:"Захлебываясь словами, сухо всхлипывая, она говорила, не слушая себя, не слыша окриков изумленного мужа,- говорила о том, что она чужая в доме, никем не любима, живет, как прислуга.(Максим Горький)"

Comment: Мы тут этот "единый знак" обсуждали. да и вообще это популярная тема на форумах. Одна из непоняток - называть ли ли всякое стечение тире и запятой единым знаком. Судя по формулировке Розеталя (я правильно понимаю, вы его прочитировали?), ответ скорее отрицательный.   
И если в последнем примере понимание "единого знака" очевидно, т.к. там нет иных причин для тире, то в исходном примере тире можно объяснить безотносительно к запятой, а следовательно трактовать их как "единый знак" не стоит.  
Это примеры на разные случаи.