# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

"Для тех, кто любит, чтобы толпа сбивала с ног, крики и музыка оглушали, нос и глаза щипал сигаретный дым, а тело покрывалось золотистым загаром (,) - этот фестиваль для вас!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ernest00, мы же с вами несколько раз обсуждали проблему стечения тире и запятой.
[Вот здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/6181/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5), например.

Спорный вопрос. Не конкретный случай, а вообще вся ситаайцмия спорная, в правилах нет однозначного ответа. Вряд ли кто-то скажет что-то новое. Я бы не ставил.